# How to force logout an user session from Partner Community

Tags: apex, community, api, oauth, open-id-connect

I have a partner community where we have two auth providers. One is being Auth1 and other is Auth2. We had Auth1 in place for long time and as maintenance cost is getting higher, we have moved to Auth2 which is a new implementation. Both are external auth providers

Now the requirememt is, to migrate all the users to Auth2's external system so that the user can log in to Salesforce, we need to force logout the existing auth1 sessions of the users. Is there any way I can acheive that. Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [AuthSession](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm) object. Just deleting the records of all the active users from this object, will end their session and they have re-login again at which time they will login using Auth2 configuration

Comment: we have a connected app which is a mobile app and in that, I can see that there is no session time out specified. Even when I delete/terminate the session in Salesforce, when i open the app, it isn't asking me to login. That means, terminating the session isn't logging me out from the app. Moreover, I can see that a new session is getting created.

Is this due to session time out which isn't specified in the connected app settings.
Please suggest

Comment: @Skumar, if its asking you to login and uses the new auth provider your requirements are met right? whats the problem with new session being created

Comment: If it ask me login then its all good, but here, it isn't asking me to login. I had logged in using auth1 and when I terminated the session, i was still logged in the app. As I said, in the connected app, we didnt specify any session time out. Is this the reason why I havent logged out of the app even when I force terminate the session in Salesforce